# Why is output power such a meaningful quantity in speakers?

Tags: power, audio, impedance-matching

Loudspeakers, for example, should be impedance matched to deliver the highest *power* from the source to the speakers. But why do we care about *power* so much? A speaker is at its simplest, a coil around a magnet connected to a flexible fabric. As the coil current changes, the coil vibrates around the magnet and thus moving the speaker fabric, creating sound waves. But isn't the amplitude of the coil vibration proportional to the *current* in the coil, not the *power* delivered to the coil? To achieve the loudest sound, shouldn't we care more about delivering the highest *current*, rather than highest *power*?

Comment: Speakers certainly shouldn't be impedance matched to their driving amplifier. That is a ludicrous assertion and just is not done period.

Comment: Some antique vacuum tube amplifiers matched the amplifier output transformer impedance to the speaker impedance. The output transformer produced poor bass response so the poor damping of the speaker resonance made listeners hear the muddy boomy sounds and think there was some bass. Modern solid state amplifiers have and extended low frequency response and a very low output impedance for excellent damping of speaker resonance.

Comment: @Audioguru They did not "match" the transformer to the speaker in "maximum power transfer" terms. They were still essentially voltage sources; low impedance output : but provided e.g. 0.25 to 1 ohm outputs to connect to 4 to 16 ohm speakers, increasing the voltage to the latter. Source : my Leak TL/10s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different speakers run at different voltages and comparing current means you cannot directly compare speakers based on current unless you know they run at the same voltage.

> But isn't the amplitude of the coil vibration proportional to the current in the coil

Sure, but number of turns also matters to produce the force produced for a given current. More turns = more wire = more resistance = more voltage to push the same current through the coil. You can design the coil to produce the same magnetic force and amplitude at high voltage at low current or low current at high voltage.

Think about it this way: current through a one loop coil uses the magnetic field from that current once. Two loops means you double back and stack tet magnetic field from that same current on top of itself twice so double the force, but twice the wire means you need double the voltage to push that same current.

Answer (score 2):

Actually speaker outputs are not impedance matched, speaker outputs have extremely low output impedance, to drive the element with voltage signal for best results, so that the voltage signal stays virtually undistorted regardless of load impedance and current.

Just as an example how to get most power into a speaker: if the amplifier has 8V supply and most power to speaker is wanted, connecting 8V to 8 ohm speaker means 1A of current and thus 8 watts of power. If you only put any resistance to speaker output in series with the speaker, current and voltage at speaker will be less so it receives less power. That is why, to minimize power loss in the amplifier, and to maximize the power received at the speaker, no impedance matching is used, and the less impedance the amp output has, the better.

A loudspeaker as a whole is more than just single inductive element, as many loudspeakers have more than one element and so they must include low pass and high pass filters.

So it makes little sense to have an impedance matched speaker output, it would just waste power at the amplifier and drive the loudspeaker poorly.

Answer (score 2):

Audio power amplifiers are ideally close to a **voltage source** having very low (sometimes even negative) output impedance. Such a power amplifier is *not impedance-matched* to a loudspeaker.
However, such a power amplifier could deliver nearly infinite power into a short-circuit. Either some component inside the amplifier fails, or a circuit limits current delivered to such a low-resistance load (causing the amplifier to run non-linearly).
The power amplifier is designed so that nothing fails, nor protection-circuits are activated when a load resistance **above a minimum value** (should be in the spec sheet) is attached. One type of protection circuit monitors current delivered to the speaker, and limits it to some maximum value that won't cause internal damage or heat. A very cheap version might use a fuse.

Some amplifiers will drive 2-ohm loads, other weaker amplifiers will drive 4-ohm loads, and most any amplifier will drive 8-ohm loads. Any load above 8-ohms can easily be driven by any power audio amplifier.

---

Amplitude of voice coil movement is affected by the mounting enclosure, as well as coil current. Amplitude of voice coil movement usually drops off at higher frequency as well. It gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You worry about power because it's easier to measure than voice coil temperature.

Loudspeakers are pretty inefficient; a high percentage of the amplifier power is dissipated as heat.

And it's usually voice coil temperature reaching the melting point of various plastics, adhesives and the insulation of the wire that limits the speaker's power handling capacity.

Voice coils can be rated for 220-240C before failure; but a 50W or 100W power rating is more generally easier to understand and choose an amplifier for.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum amplifier power output would be related to its maximum undistorted RMS output voltage and current. It's output impedance would be very low in order to deliver maximum output. The speaker impedance would need to be high enough to avoid amplifier overload.

The maximum speaker current would be dependent on the speaker impedance and the amplifier maximum output voltage. The voice coil winding would need to be sized to carry that current. The maximum voltage and current relate to the maximum power that can handled by the speaker.

The sensitivity of a speaker is the sound output, in dB, derived from it with one watt of power fed from an amplifier.

The efficiency of a home speaker (ratio of accoustic energy output to electrical energy input) would be as low as 1%.